# Dashboard is empty for roles apart from admin

Tags: dashboard

I want to create a role specific dashboard on drupal 7.
So I have added some blocks on the dashboard and also the "View dashboard" permission for this role.
However,when I login using the above role,the dashboard is empty.
What is the reason for this and how can I fix that?
P.S.Admin can see these blocks on dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have assign blocks to the region of non admin theme. If so, you have to assign the blocks to the region of admin theme(seven or enabled admin theme in your drupal system).